# Curvature Characterization of Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

A (Riemnnian) symmetric space is locally characterized by the first covariant derivative of its curvature tensor, namely, a manifold $M$ is locally a symmetric space if and only if $\nabla R=0$ (where $R$ stands for the Riemannian curvature tensor).

Is there a similar characterization for homogeneous manifolds?

More specifically, I wonder if the condition $(\nabla_XR)(Y\,X)X=0$ (for all $X,Y\in TM$) is sufficient.

I apologize if it is well-known.

Comment: See page 413, Theorem 2.1 here : http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/50-4/411.pdf

Comment: @Holonomia : Thank you for the comment. This is certainly an answer to the question, but I still wonder if the equality above makes any sense.

Comment: It seems to me that the equality above is closer to properties (C) and (P) in Theorem 1, page 59 here http://ac.els-cdn.com/092622459290009C/1-s2.0-092622459290009C-main.pdf?_tid=9b8e720a-c9a8-11e5-889f-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1454416350_5bb235b6856bbff2476848d11ba4571d

Comment: @Holonomia Since I found the answeres in through your comments, wouldn't you like to write it down as an answer so I could accept it? (The identiy I was seeking makes the space symmetric as in Lemma 5.1 of http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01457081)

Comment: I am happy my comments were helpful for you.  It is not necessary to write my answer down. Your comment it is enough to me.